# Проблема с POST через JSON RPC

Tags: javascript, rest, json-rpc

Дали задачу на работе - синхронизировать через API товары поставщика и сайт начальника. Требуется пройти аунтитефикацию а потом через get вытянуть json таблицы товаров.
Пробовал через curl, но ничего не понял, инфы в инете мало.
[image: Руководство поставщика]

Решил скачать postman и там через body -> GraphQL вставил этот запрос, но в ответ пришло лишь
[image: Ответ от сайта поставщика]

Не понимаю как отправить post Запрос через json rpc. Помогите пожалуйста, скажите куда двигаться.

Comment: Попробуйте через body => raw => json

Comment: О, помогло. Спасибо большое. Я видимо еще одну лишнюю кавычку добавлял, эх, прям нет слов как я рад что наконец то решил эту проблему. Пасибо еще раз! c:

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста) Скорее всего проблема заключалась в том, что GraphGL и обычный json - два совершенно разных способа обратиться к серверу